# Multiply lines of a text file - need fix

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiplication

I was given a code to multiply the lines in a text file:

---

This is my basic text file:

**Text_1.txt (Open_File)**:

```
1
2
3
4
```

---

**The code:**

```
file = Open_file

with open(file, "r") as f:
    file = f.read()

file_multiply = file * 3

with open('multiply.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(file_multiply)
```

---

**The problem is, multiply.txt (the outfile) looks like this:**

```
1
2
3
41
2
3
41
2
3
4
```

---

(The problem is that the "1" is not at the beginning of the line.)
Do you have a solution for this?
I've provided the code to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put newline characters between each item you write.

```
with open('multiply.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n'.join([file]*3))
```